# Failed to load OpenCL runtime in OpenCV for Python

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, opencl

I am trying to run the first example [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html), but I am getting this error. I am using Ubuntu 13.10.

```
Failed to load OpenCL runtime
OpenCV Error: Unknown error code -220 (OpenCL function is not available: [clGetPlatformIDs]) in opencl_check_fn, file /home/cristi/opencv/modules/core/src/opencl/runtime/opencl_core.cpp, line 204
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /home/cristi/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3159
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cristi/opencv1/src/video.py", line 11, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /home/cristi/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3159: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Also, this is the line that is causing the trouble (line 11 in my code):

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Failed to load OpenCL runtime

Most probably there is some problem with your installation. If you are not working with GPU, then I recommend you to turn off all CUDA/OpenCL modules in OpenCV during compilation.

> error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor

This error says your input image should have 3 channel (BGR/color image) or 4 channel(RGBA image). So please check number of channels in `frame` by executing `print frame.shape`.

Since you are working with video, there is a high chance that your camera is not opened for capture, so that frame is not captured. In that case, `print frame.shape` will say it is `NoneType` data.

I recommend you to run the same code with an image instead of video. Even then if the error of OpenCL shows up, it is most likely a problem with your installation. If it works fine, problem may be with VideoCapture. You can check it as mentioned in the same tutorial:

> Sometimes, **cap** may not have initialized the capture. In that case,
>   this code shows error. You can check whether it is initialized or not
>   by the method **cap.isOpened()**. If it is True, OK.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You were right, it says that it is `NoneType`, what should I do next? However, the error in my original post happens with a video as well, not just when my laptop's camera is involved. Just mentioning it in case it is relevant.

Comment: Is the problem with camera capture? what is result of `print cap.isOpened()` ? If it is False, it means your are OpenCV cannot initialize your camera. You may need to check your installation.

Comment: Yes, it is False indeed. Are there any straightforward steps that I can take to fix this? Can't find anything on Google.

Comment: I don't know any except compiling from source again with correct packages installed. Can you post output of `print cv2.getBuildInformation()` in pastebin.com and provide the link here, please?

Answer (score 14):

As for the OpenCL failure, try installing required packages:

`sudo apt-get install ocl-icd-opencl-dev`

Worked for me. My guess is that OCL is a part of the `opencv_core` module, and if it failed to initialise, then many other components might behave strange.

Comment: Worked for me, I think that's the right way to fix the problem.

Comment: I now realise that failure to grab a frame would also throw an error at the `cvtColor()` of the sort mentioned in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to install/update the driver: http://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2011-12-29/opencl-hardware-support/

Updating the driver help to solve my problem with OpenCL